# Laurent series, function representation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, laurent-series

Write the Laurent series for the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z}$ $1<|z|<\infty$

I did
$$\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty z^n\rightarrow \frac{1}{1+z}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^nz^n$$
Is it right? There is a general procedure for me to check if the series I wrote is correct for a particular function?

In this case the restriction $1<|z|<\infty$ is just by the fact of function have a singularity point in 1?

Comment: What you wrote is the Laurent series for $\lvert z\rvert < 1$ (which happens to be the Taylor series). That's the wrong domain. You need a series that converges for $\lvert z\rvert > 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the series you wrote converges only if $|z|<1$.
$$
\frac 1 {1-z} = \frac{1/z}{(1/z)-1} = \frac {-1} z \left(\frac 1 {1-\frac 1 z}\right) = \frac{-1} z \left( 1 + \frac 1 z + \frac 1 {z^2} + \frac 1{z^3} +\cdots \right) =\cdots
$$
This converges when $|z|>1$.

Comment: So I always have to apply a convergence test to check my answers?

Comment: @askazy : I'm looking at my old copy of Lars Ahlfors' _Complex Analysis_ and I don't find an explicit definition of "Laurent series".  I find a section titled "The Laurent Series" and an explanation that the region of convergence is an annulus $R_1<|z|<R_2$, and then it goes on to explain that if the domain of a holomorphic function contains an annulus $R_1<|z-a|<R_2$ then it is equal within that region to the sum of a convergent series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} A_n(z-a)^n$.  So I would take that to mean convergence is essentially part of the definition. ${}\qquad{}$